# IE6 rending UL's incorrectly

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6, rendering

Sometimes IE6 will render the text of a `<ul>` list the same color as the background color. If you select it, they show back up, or if you scroll the page up and back down.

It is obviously a rendering bug, but I was wondering if anyone knows of a workaround to make it reliable?

Comment: Do you have an example of this problem? I imagine there is something else on the page or some script that is causing the inconsistent behaviour...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try giving it hasLayout with

```css
zoom: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried explicitly setting a line-height? For some reason this seems to be the solution to a great many IE6 rendering bugs!

e.g.

```css
.mylist {
    line-height: 1.6em;
}
```